# Can't resize same file in 2 seperate formats . Intervention Image - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

Using: `Laravel 5.2` , `Intervention Image` http://image.intervention.io/

I have a form with the possibility to upload an image. This image gets resized and stored on my server . This all works perfectly , but i recently had the need to make a second image size. So i did the following:

**Controller**

```
// Resize uploaded thumbnail and return the temporary file path
        $thumbnail = $request->file('thumbnail');
        $thumbnail_url = $this->storeTempImage($thumbnail,350,230);
        $video_thumbnail_url = $this->storeTempImage($thumbnail,1140,640);
```

StoreTempImage Method

```
  public function storeTempImage($uploadedImage, $width, $height) 
    {
        //resize and save image to temporary storage
        $originalName = $uploadedImage->getClientOriginalName();
        $name = time() . $originalName;
        $uploadedImage->move('images/temp/', $name);

        Image::make("images/temp/{$name}")->fit($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->upsize();
        })->save("images/temp/{$name}");

        return "images/temp/{$name}";
    }
```

After i post the form my first image gets correctly saved, but after that it throws an error:

> The file "myfile.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.

**What i've tried**

1. My first idea was that the `time()` function was not specific enough and that the file had the same name. So i changed `time()` to `microtime(true)`
2. I made 2 seperate methods for the image sizes

Both solutions didn't work and threw the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're using same object to create and save the image, you should do it like this:

```
public function storeTempImage($uploadedImage, $width, $height) 
{
    // Creating Image Intervention Instance
    $img = Image::make($uploadedImage);
    $originalName = $uploadedImage->getClientOriginalName();

    // Include the below line if you want to store this image, else leave it
    $uploadedImage->move('images/temp/', time() . $originalName);

    // Cropping the image according to given params
    $new_img = $img->fit($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->upsize();
    })->save("images/temp/" . time() . $originalName);

    return $new_img;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Note that i want to return the path to the images not the image object itself. But i changed that myself. But after i added your code i got a different error : Unable to read image from file ().

Comment: on `$video_thumbnail_url = $this->storeTempImage($thumbnail,1140,640);` 
So the moment it wants to run the method a second time.

Comment: Don't use clone as you're passing a new instance of variable everytime when you're calling the method `storeTempImage()`

Comment: not sure what you mean by that last statement, I'm not using clone?. Do you mean i should use `$request->file('thumbnail')` two times instead of the $thumbnail or ? Sorry for not understanding.  I also found this: http://image.intervention.io/api/reset not sure if that would help me somehow

Comment: Give uploaded image url path inside `make()` method

Comment: The image is coming from a Html-form so i don't have a path yet.

Comment: Try to give this path - `'images/temp/', time() . $originalName` after moving the image

Comment: That only means i resize the first image . Can't figure it out, so i have used another approach currently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
    $thumbnail = $request->file('thumbnail');
    $thumbnail_url = $this->storeTempImage($thumbnail,350,230);
    $video_thumbnail_url = $this->storeTempImage(clone $thumbnail,1140,640);
    $video_thumbnail_url = $this->storeTempImage($thumbnail,1140,640);
```

You send OBJECT to `storeTempImage()` - and you modify this object in line

```
$uploadedImage->move('images/temp/', $name);
```

I think you must have 2 objects - in another way it's not working good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solutions but it didn't solve it. But you are probably on to something about using the same object twice. Not really sure how to solve it tho.

Comment: @Christophvh give me a time to install Laravel and test it locally.